# Using django generic views

Tags: django, django-views, django-generic-views

I am getting an error using the deleteview while create and update view are working fine and I want to redirect my deleteview to my index page My codes are:-

Views.py-

```
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from .models import Album

class AlbumDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Album
    success_url = reverse_lazy('music:index')
```

urls.py-

```
url(r'^album/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$', views.AlbumDelete.as_view(), 
name='album-delete'),
```

music/index.html -

```
`<a href="{% url 'music:album-delete' album.id %}"><span class="glyphicon 
glyphicon-trash"></span></a>`
```

Error is

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /polls/album/2/delete/

Comment: I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have your default view. Please check [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.DeleteView)

Example myapp/author_confirm_delete.html:

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<p>Are you sure you want to delete "{{ object }}"?</p>
<input type="submit" value="Confirm" />
```